# RNN/LSTM: Out of memory when building one-hot representation

Tags: numpy, out-of-memory, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I am building a translation RNN LSTM model with encoder-decoder architecture. It does translation from language to language. Input file contains lines of tab-separated pairs of language samples.

I have created a data preprocessing class to help me get data ready for different RNNs.

```
import numpy as np

CONFIG = {
    'file_path'     : 'translation_pairs.tsv',
    'col_separator' : '\t',
    'word_separator': '',
    'enc_data_col'  : 0,
    'dec_data_col'  : 1,
    'case_sensivive': False
}


class RnnData:
    def __init__(self, conf):
        self.enc_data  = []
        self.dec_data  = []
        self.conf      = conf

        with open(conf['file_path']) as file:
            if not conf['case_sensivive']:
                lines = file.read().lower().split('\n')
            else:
                lines = file.read().split('\n')

        enc_set = set()
        dec_set = set()

        for line in lines:
            cols = line.split(conf['col_separator'])
            for n in range(len(cols)):
                if n == conf['enc_data_col']:
                    self.enc_data.append(cols[n])
                    self._vocab(cols[n], enc_set)
                elif n == conf['dec_data_col']:
                    self.dec_data.append(cols[n])
                    self._vocab(cols[n], dec_set)

        self.enc_vocab       = dict([(char, i) for i, char in enumerate(sorted(list(enc_set)))])
        self.dec_vocab       = dict([(char, i) for i, char in enumerate(sorted(list(dec_set)))])
        self.enc_vocab_len   = len(self.enc_vocab)
        self.dec_vocab_len   = len(self.dec_vocab)
        self.enc_max_seq_len = max([len(s) for s in self.enc_data])
        self.dec_max_seq_len = max([len(s) for s in self.dec_data])
        self.samples_len     = len(lines)

        print('Number of samples:\t\t',             self.samples_len)
        print('Number of unique input tokens:\t',   self.enc_vocab_len)
        print('Number of unique output tokens:\t',  self.dec_vocab_len)
        print('Max sequence length for inputs:\t',  self.enc_max_seq_len)
        print('Max sequence length for outputs:',   self.dec_max_seq_len)

        self._gen_one_hot()

    def _gen_one_hot(self):
        self.enc_oh_input = np.zeros(
            (self.samples_len, self.enc_max_seq_len, self.enc_vocab_len), dtype='int8')
        self.dec_oh_input = np.zeros(
            (self.samples_len, self.dec_max_seq_len, self.dec_vocab_len), dtype='int8')
        self.dec_oh_output = np.zeros(
            (self.samples_len, self.dec_max_seq_len, self.dec_vocab_len), dtype='int8')

        for i, (text_in, text_out) in enumerate(zip(self.enc_data, self.dec_data)):
            for t, char in enumerate(text_in):
                self.enc_oh_input[i, t, self.enc_vocab[char]] = 1
            self.enc_oh_input[i, t + 1:, self.enc_vocab[' ']] = 1

            for t, char in enumerate(text_out):
                # self.dec_oh_output is ahead of decoder_input_data by one timestep
                self.dec_oh_input[i, t, self.dec_vocab[char]] = 1
                if t > 0:
                    # self.dec_oh_output will be ahead by one timestep
                    # and will not include the start character.
                    self.dec_oh_output[i, t - 1, self.dec_vocab[char]] = 1
            self.dec_oh_input[i, t + 1:, self.dec_vocab[' ']] = 1
            self.dec_oh_output[i, t:, self.dec_vocab[' ']] = 1

    def _vocab(self, w, _set):
        a = list(w) if self.conf['word_separator'] == '' else w.slpit(self.conf['word_separator'])
        for s in a:
            _set.add(s)


rd = RnnData(CONFIG)
```

Later the data is consumed by RNN like so:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input,LSTM,Dense

batch_size=64
epochs=100
latent_dim=256

# Define an input sequence and process it.
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, rd.enc_vocab_len))
encoder = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
# We discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Set up the decoder, using `encoder_states` as initial state.
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, rd.dec_vocab_len))
# We set up our decoder to return full output sequences,
# and to return internal states as well. We don't use the
# return states in the training model, but we will use them in inference.
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs,
                                     initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(rd.dec_vocab_len, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)


# Define the model that will turn
# `encoder_input_data` & `decoder_input_data` into `decoder_target_data`
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)

# Run training
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit([rd.enc_oh_input, rd.dec_oh_input], rd.dec_oh_output,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_split=0.2)
```

During the first step, in `_gen_one_hot()` call, I am running out of memory, which is understandable considering large matrix size.

Output from `__init__()`:

> ```
> Number of samples:                 467120
> Number of unique input tokens:     67
> Number of unique output tokens:    104
> Max sequence length for inputs:    537
> Max sequence length for outputs:   475
> ```

I've explored various solutions including `to_categorical()` in Kreas.
Perhaps, there is a way to do this while writing and reading a file in the disk batch-by-batch, but I don't know how to modify the way data is consumed by the model. Or maybe there is a better trick.

Please share your wisdom